# Android Studio ImageButton changing shape after implementing a style

Tags: android, xml

I've searched here and it doesn't seem like anyone has had this problem.

I'm following the Android Studio tutorials from [here.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-drawables-styles-and-themes/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#4)

Basically what is happening is that my buttons look fine when I implement my XML code, but when I transfer over some of the XML code to my `styles.xml` and import it into my `activity_main.xml` file, my button changes its dimensions.

Here's my `activity_main.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16sp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/decreaseTeam1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_minus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/minus_button"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:onClick="decreaseScore" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/increaseTeam1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/plus_button"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="increaseScore"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/initial_score"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team1_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/team_1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/decreaseTeam2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_minus"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:contentDescription="@string/minus_button"
            android:onClick="decreaseScore"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/increaseTeam2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/plus_button"
            android:onClick="increaseScore"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/initial_score"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team2_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/team_2"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My `strings.xml` file.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Scorekeeper</string>
    <string name="team_2">Team 2</string>
    <string name="initial_score">0</string>
    <string name="plus_button">Plus Button</string>
    <string name="minus_button">Minus Button</string>
    <string name="team_1">Team 1</string>
</resources>
```

`drawable.ic_minus`:

```
<vector android:height="40dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="40dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M19,13H5v-2h14v2z"/>
</vector>
```

`drawable.ic_plus`:

```
<vector android:height="40dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="40dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

`drawable.button_background`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

I hope I have not missed anything out. If you copy paste my code inside an empty activity `activity_main.xml` file, you should see something like this.

[image]

Now the problem:
I want to implement some styles for my buttons. I have updated my `styles.xml` as such. In this case I have a parent `ScoreButton` which only takes the background, whereas the child elements are the plus and minus, which takes the picture and description.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ScoreButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PlusButtons" parent="ScoreButtons">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_plus</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/plus_button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MinusButtons" parent="ScoreButtons">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_minus</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/minus_button</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

And if I update one of my button's code as such, for instance, replacing `@+id/decreaseTeam1` with the code below:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/decreaseTeam1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="@style/PlusButtons"
        android:onClick="decreaseScore" />
```

The minus button suddenly becomes inflated.

[image]

I read that child views override parent views, but I don't see how that can be a problem, since there is no change to the image size, nor have I compressed it.

Comment: I see I see, I'll take note of that in the future.

Comment: @YipJungHon you are making a mistake in styles you should use ImageButton instead of using Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the style definition, your `ScoreButtons` has `Widget.AppCompat.Button` as parent. This style defines a minHeight and minWidth, as follows:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">88dip</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

So, in order to solve your problem, you just have to remove the parent from `ScoreButtons` style:

```
<style name="ScoreButtons">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your style. You are using an `ImageButton` not a `Button`

So, you should write

```
<style name="ScoreButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">  // ImageButton
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making a mistake while assigning a style. you need to use ImageButton instead of using Button.

Use this:

```
  <style name="ScoreButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/minus_button</item>
    </style>
```

Instead of this:

```
      <style name="ScoreButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/minus_button</item>
    </style>
```